# Setup WiFi via ONVIF

Tags: onvif, hikvision

I'm working with Hikvision DS-2CD2443G0-IW. And can't understand if it possible to setup WiFi via ONVIF. I'm little confused with non-consistent output

**GetDot11Capabilities** returns next:

```
<tds:GetDot11CapabilitiesResponse>
    <tds:Capabilities>
        <tt:TKIP>true</tt:TKIP>
        <tt:ScanAvailableNetworks>true</tt:ScanAvailableNetworks>
        <tt:MultipleConfiguration>true</tt:MultipleConfiguration>
        <tt:AdHocStationMode>false</tt:AdHocStationMode>
        <tt:WEP>true</tt:WEP>
    </tds:Capabilities>
</tds:GetDot11CapabilitiesResponse>
```

So, I understand that ScanAvailableNetworks is available.

But in the same time **GetCapabilities** return

```
<tt:Network>
    <tt:IPFilter>true</tt:IPFilter>
    <tt:ZeroConfiguration>true</tt:ZeroConfiguration>
    <tt:IPVersion6>true</tt:IPVersion6>
    <tt:DynDNS>true</tt:DynDNS>
    <tt:Extension>
        <tt:Dot11Configuration>false</tt:Dot11Configuration>
        <tt:Extension>
            <tt:DHCPv6>true</tt:DHCPv6>
            <tt:Dot1XConfigurations>0</tt:Dot1XConfigurations>
        </tt:Extension>
    </tt:Extension>
</tt:Network>
```

and **ScanAvailableDot11Networks** returns 500 error with "Optional Action Not Implemented" inside.

What am I doing wrong and is there any better way to understand if WiFi setup possible via
ONVIF at all?